# Copy google script from one (spread)sheet to another

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Im new on google sripts and trying to improve.
I was given a task to copy scripts from old spreadheet to new spreadsheet. It is possible ?
Thank you.
P.s. I looked up for this question in google but didn't found reliable answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure.

- Open one of the sample spreadsheets
- Copy it to your drive
- Open that copy
- Menu: Tools -> Script Editor
- Copy and paste contents into desired spreadsheet

Caution: If copied script makes reference to the old spreadsheet using a specific spreadsheet ID (via SpreadsheetApp.openById() for example) you'll need to tailor your code accordingly.
Likewise for explicitly named sheets, folders and data. Presumably, you're reading up on the help docs? https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. But is here a way to **build a script that will do that** work (copy-paste scripts from old sheet to new one) ? This is what I'm trying to achieve. 
This simple method I already know.

Comment: Oh. No - scripts can't create other scripts.

Comment: Not the only method, per se - you could try publishing an app as an add-on and effectively import code that way. Even then, that add-on wouldn't be able to call or install external code. But programmatically, there isn't a way (at least, that I know of) yet. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.